# Installing Python's TripleSec library on Fedora 22

Tags: python, linux, encryption, pip, fedora

I've tried the

```
pip install TripleSec
```

and it seems to install fine but when i run *triplesec* in terminal i get the following error:

```
import sha3 AttributeError: module object has no attribute '__get_builtin_constructor'
```

I've tried installing *sha3* seperately as well but no luck.

Is there something special you need to try?

Comment: Python TripleSec is compatible with Python 2.6, 2.7 and 3.3. Witch version do you have?

Comment: OK, i'm trying to see if I have the same issue

Comment: can you give the exact version number, it seems that there is some people having issue with the version 2.7.9

Comment: The latest python version is 2.7.10  (for 2.7)

Comment: The version I have is Python 2.7.10

Comment: I did a successful install of Python TripleSec, you may be missing some thing, i will post the steps shortly

Comment: i got: Successfully built TripleSec pycrypto scrypt pysha3 twofish salsa20
Installing collected packages: pycrypto, scrypt, six, pysha3, twofish, salsa20, TripleSec
Successfully installed TripleSec-0.3 pycrypto-2.6.1 pysha3-0.3 salsa20-0.3.0 scrypt-0.7.1 six-1.10.0 twofish-0.3.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first I did a fresh install of Fedora Workstation 22 in a virtual machine for me

And then I found that i have Python 2.7.9 installed and not 2.7.10

So I downloaded Python-2.7.10.tar.xz

Link: https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.10/Python-2.7.10.tar.xz

Decompress the source

Enter the directory Python-2.7.10

before begining the installation, we have to install the dependancies:

> 1. yum groupinstall "Development tools"
> 2. yum install zlib-devel bzip2-devel openssl-devel ncurses-devel sqlite-devel readline-devel tk-devel gdbm-devel db4-devel libpcap-devel xz-devel
> 3. enter the director Python-2.7.10 and type:
>
>    ./configure
>
>    make
>
>    make install

Now download the script file for pip tool:
https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

Then install pip:

> python get-pip.py

Final step: install Python TripleSec

> pip install TripleSec

here is what i got:
[image]

It's successfully installed

And when you execute in terminal you have this output (**WITHOUT THE ERRORS MENTIONED IN THE QUESTION**):

[image]

Comment: were you able to run it in terminal?

Comment: What do you mean exactly ? I do not have an example about TripleSec, I answered for the errors when you try to install, that what exactly you asked for .

Comment: the error occurs when you try to run it - if you type in 'triplesec' in terminal. It doesnt work, which is why I asked if tthere was a specific way to install it on fedora.

Comment: It works for me, look at the result I will update my answer

Comment: As you see, it's working and i have to supply some arguments as indicated by the error message

Comment: Try to follow carefully the installation and please consider upvote the answer and/or accept it. I can answer your questions if you have things still unclear.

Comment: On a fedora virtual machine, after running the get-pip file and trying to run 'pip install TripleSec' I get the following error: 'File /usr/bin/pip, line 7, in <module>
from pip import main
ImportError: no module named pip

Comment: I'll look at that as soon as possible with another VM, fedora 22, fresh install